# Inserting Special symbols into VB 2010 button?

Tags: vb.net

I am designing a scientific calculator as a Microsoft windows calculator. 
The problem when I design is I can't to insert special symbols like picture illustrated.
How to insert those [image]type of symbols in VB 2010 buttons to display it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click Windows 7 start button and search for `Character Map`, pick a character you want, then copy/paste into Button's Text property assignment. Alternatively, go to:

- Start -> All Programs -> Accessories -> System Tools -> Character Map

Either way you should be seeing a tool like this:

[image]

Credit:

- [Superscript Text In Names Of Lables And Buttons](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/75618-superscript-text-in-names-of-lables-and-buttons/)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign an image to the buttons `.Image` property. Align the image to the buttons center with the `.ImageAlign` property and remove the content of the `.Text` property.

That way you can design the formulas in any formula editor you like and add them as images to your buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Yes using this method worked for me.

Click Windows 7 start button and search for Character Map, pick a character you want, then copy/paste into Button's Text property assignment. Alternatively, go to:

Start -> All Programs -> Accessories -> System Tools -> Character Map
Either way you should be seeing a tool like this:

enter image description here